# Apex chart fill colors facing issue in Angular

Tags: angular, apexcharts, column-chart

Can anyone please help me out here in bellow code for apex charts with angular

```
  fill: {
            colors: [function({ value, seriesIndex, w }) {
              if(value < 55) {
                  return '#7E36AF'
              } else if (value >= 55 && value < 80) {
                  return '#164666'
              } else {
                  return '#D9534F'
              }
            }]
          }
```

I my displaying the colors for column chart using apex charts in angular but facing error
**"(local function)({ value, seriesIndex, w }: any): "#7E36AF" | "#164666" | "#D9534F"
Type '({ value, seriesIndex, w }: any) => "#7E36AF" | "#164666" | "#D9534F"' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2322)"**

If the same I try in JavaScript it work's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like an issue with the types.

I have updated it on [GitHub](https://github.com/apexcharts/ng-apexcharts/commit/4aa84e8760605fc47c660f50f7f7347e6297ab75) and a new version of ng-apexcharts will be released soon.